# URL rewriting regex with optional capturing

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have these types of URLs:

```
/manage/123
/manage_foo/456
/manage_bar/789

/manage
/manage_foo
/manage_bar
```

I need to rewrite to:

```
/manage.php?id=123
/manage_foo.php?id=456
/manage_bar.php?id=789

/manage.php?id=
/manage_foo.php?id=
/manage_bar.php?id=
```

How do I make the capturing of the `id` optional? I know this works if an `id` is present:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(manage.*)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1.php?id=%2 [NC,L]
```

That regex breaks down if you remove the slash before the `id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(manage)(?:/([0-9]*))?/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Can you change it so that it requires a `manage` at the beginning? e.g. `/manage.*/123`